# Which units does $d_H=3t$ have?

Tags: cosmology

In a flat, without cosmological constant and matter-dominated universe, the equation $d_H=3t$ holds, relating the particle horizon to time, but my calculations seem underestimated by maaaaaany orders of magnitude when I use it... So I determined I'm definitely not using the right units. Which ones should I be plugging in? Thanks!

Comment: What are you using? Are they compatible with $c=1$? Or you can put the $c$ back in and use any units you want.

Comment: Forgot about that... I'm still far from the precise solution to my exercise but yeah, now it matches the order of magnitude at least

Comment: If t represents time, why would you not choose seconds as the unit?